# Selenium: Element not located via LINK_TEXT or PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to find a robust way to locate the logout link in a dropdown user menu in a web app. This is the html for for the link:

```
<a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>
```

I have attempted the following:

```
    /** The logout link */
@FindBy(how = How.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, using = "Logout")
private WebElement logoutLink;
```

and

```
    /** The logout link */
@FindBy(how = How.LINK_TEXT, using = "Logout")
private WebElement logoutLink;
```

However, I keep getting a NoSuchElementException when attempting the access the logout link. The LINK_TEXT method worked previously and mysteriously stopped working in the last few days. I tried the PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT method just for kicks and it fails as well. Is there any reason anyone can give me why this is failing to locate the link. I use PageFactory.initElements on the class that includes this link and other web elements are located without a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a defect in Selenium. I've entered a bug and will be posting a sample page and script to reproduce it sometime next week.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5772

Answer (score 2):

Please check the actual text for the link once again. It's not working may be there can be spaces or may be upper case , lower case in the text.
You can also try,

```
@FindBy(linkText = “Logout”)
```

Partial Link Text

```
@FindBy(partialLinkText = “Logout”)
```

Comment: The link text is included in the snippet of the html from the web page I'm trying to locate the logout link on. The text is just 'Logout', no spaces or other special characters. I will try your alternative FindBy annotation suggestion later today.

Comment: @FindBy(linkText = “Logout”)

and
     @FindBy(partialLinkText = “Logout”) both fail to locate the element. I still get a NoSuchElementException. The only think that seems to work is an XPath, which is brittle and slow.

Comment: @Selena please check the onclick string that should match.  <input type="button" name="logout" value="logout" />

Comment: There's no button. It's just a link in a dropdown menu: <a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a>